# How can i add a onclick to resoponse of autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Here is my script

```
$('#id').autocomplete({ 
                source: function( request, response ) { 
                    $.ajax({
                        url : path,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                           id: request.term
                        },
                         success: function( data ) {
                             response( 
                         $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.id,
                                    value: item.id
                                }  
                            }));
                        } 
                    });
                }, 
                autoFocus: true,
                minLength: 0                       
              });
```

while clciking on label i need a alert of that value? How can ik make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen to [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event.

```
$('#id').autocomplete({ 
    source: function( request, response ) { 
      // ...
    }, 
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) {
       alert(ui.item.value);
    }           
});
```

Comment: How can i change style of autocomplete llist?